# Which design consumes less memory?

Tags: java, memory

IF I have an `interface In1` and two classes `c1,c2` which implement `In1`  
And if i have two classes `x1,x2` which just have their own methods 
 which **behave the same way as  `c1,c2`** like:

```
In1  i1 = new c1();
i1 = new c2();
```

and

```
X1 x1 = new x1();
X2 x2 = new x2();
```

Which of the above consumes more **memory** ?

Comment: Unless you have a billion of these objects it is unlikely to matter. The difference will be a fraction of a cent of memory in this case.

Comment: Java also runs in embedded systems, where memory can be quite limited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the implementations are otherwise identical, whether or not the classes implement interface(s) will not significantly alter runtime memory requirements.

Looking specifically at your code

```
In1  i1 = new c1();
i1 = new c2();
```

and

```
X1 x1 = new x1();
X2 x2 = new x2();
```

In the first block, your instance of c1 is no longer referenced once i1 = new c2() is run. That makes it eligible for garbage collection.  That code block is not the same as the second code block, because the second code block maintains a reference to both allocated objects.

However, if you rewrite your first code block as

```
In1  i1a = new c1();
In1  i1b = new c2();
```

your memory requirements are again exactly the same with or without interfaces, because you hold a reference to the objects for the same duration.

**UPDATE**

If you mark methods of your class *final*, I believe you will save slightly on memory allocation due to the fact that a [vtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606481/virtual-table-dispatch-table) is not needed. Methods declared in [interfaces cannot be marked final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453287/why-is-final-not-allowed-in-java-8-interface-methods).

Comment: There will probably be some minor memory increase on the side of the `Class` object for the class implementing an interface.

Comment: @JiriTousek: I suspect that interface implementation is managed entirely at compile time. If a method in the class were marked final, that would reduce the memory footprint a bit because it would remove the need for a vtable. However, final methods cannot be used with interfaces. I'll update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Interface implementetion is retained at runtime. If it wasn't, the runtime could not check a runtime cast like `MyInterface bar = (MyInterface) foo`, and you couldn't use [`Class.getInterfaces()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getInterfaces--) and [`Class.isAssignableFrom()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom-java.lang.Class-).

Comment: @JiriTousek: I don't think that is overhead per instance though, just information associated with the type. Sure it has to be stored but it's likely just a few extra bytes, once.

Comment: Agreed, see my first comment: "minor memory increase on the side of `Class` object ...". Likely a few bytes of constant overhead not growing with number of instances, but you can't call it "exactly the same".