# invoking methods higher up the hierarchy level ( grandparent) without using an instance

Tags: java, android

Hi i have three classes as follows ,Class A which is parent ,Class B which is a subclass of A and does not have anything in it , Class C which is a subclass of B and a Test Class with the main function:

```
public class A {    
  double pay =0.0;    
  public double calculatePay(int hoursWorked,double rate) {    
    pay = hoursWorked*rate;      
    return pay;
  }    
}

public class B extends A {
}

public class C extends B { 
  public double show() {
    double paid = calculatePay(10, 1.3); 
     return paid;
  }
}

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {        
    C c = new  C();        
    System.out.println(c.show());           
  }
```

}

My question is how is it that i can call the `calculatePay()` method of the grandparent Class A from the Class C without using an instance/object.From my understanding of inheritance i would have thought that i would need an instance of A or C in order to invoke the grandparent method like this even though i know i have inherited the calculatePay method from A i would still require an instance of A or C ?

```
A a = new A();
a.calculatePay;
```

or

```
C c = new C();
c.calculatePay;
```

I couldnt use the super keyword because A is not a parent to C but a grandparent.Instead i just called it like this and stored it in a double variable:

```
  double paid = calculatePay(10, 1.3);
```

And when i run the program from main () it works and gives me the correct output according to the logic in the grandparent.Can someone please explain this ?
I have seen this in android programming where you call getMethods() from a grandparent within classes which are like 3 levels down the hierarchy

Comment: Hi - this is the basic model of object oriented inheritance, typically super and sub class are used in your context not parent and child.

Comment: "I couldnt use the super keyword because A is not a parent to C but a grandparent" are you saying you found you *can't*, or merely you think it *wouldn't* work?

Comment: hi thanks for replying but you dint answer my question ? Elemental

Comment: Andy i didnt try it out  because from what i read super refers to your direct parent ? which in my case the parent of C is B but i have tried it now and it seems to work also,how is that i thought super is only refers to a call to you parent class not your grand parent andy-turner

Comment: i will GhostCat but if you know a little about what am asking would you kindly share your answer also ? need all the help i can get

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback. Sure, if you have more specific questions, we can talk about that a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the method is inherited, both would work - you just need the correct **syntax**:

```
A a = new A();
a.calculatePay(10, 1.3);
```

Very same if you used `C c = new C()` instead.

You don't have to do *anything* special in Java - as (non-private) methods declared in the A class can be invoked on instances of subclasses.

Beyond that: as of now, there is no sense in having 3 different classes. There is **no point** in B extending A and being *empty*. You don't write down `B extends A` because you **can**. You do such things because it makes *sense* to do so - because it helps you solving your problem.

Your problem doesn't require three classes and inheritance at all.

And regarding your actual question: you have to understand that OO languages like Java or C++ typically a "table" approach. Meaning: when you invoke a method on an object, what happens is that "the system" looks into a table for the class of that object - and that table tells it "which" method to call (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606481/virtual-table-dispatch-table) for further reading). In that sense, it doesn't make any difference if you do

```
this.foo() ... within class Foo
```

or

```
someFooObject.foo()
```

And that is exactly what *your* code is doing - by just saying `calculatePay(10, 1.3)` within C.show() ... you are invoking that method on the `this` reference implicitly.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying i just used B inorder to create a hierarchy level upto level 3 .so your saying i can use any method from even a great grandparent  without using an instance as long as the method is public and inherited ? because what i did was : calculatePay(int ,double) without using an instance and it worked fine.Note i did not use an instance and that was my main question ? kindly elaborate

Comment: @kobewarui What do you mean by "without using an instance"? By calling `a.calculatePay()` or `c.calculatePay()`, you _are_ using an instance, namely `a` or `c`, respectively.

Comment: daniu if you look at my question i used a and c to elaborat but i did not instantiate a and c in my code above

Comment: Ghostcat thats true but in my case if you look closely at class C i used calculatePay() without using an object ? was this added implicitly ? if so would it mean that this refers to class C which does not have a calculatePay() method ?

Comment: @kobewarui When you dont use an object explicitly, you call on **this**. That is why I put up that example! A method is **always** invoked "on" an object (at least in Java). When there is no object written down, then **this** is used.

Comment: sorry i never saw your explanation on "this" atleast now it makes sense.Implicitly using this to call calculatePay like : this.calculatePay ? .if so thanks now my question is fully answered

Answer (score 0):

When you are making an instance of class C, **you are already invoking the method calculatePay from class A as it is not overridden in any other class**.

Assuming that you have some functionality defined in class B and the calculatePay() method is overridden in class C, so that the code makes sense, You can override the calculatePay in B and call A's calculatePay using super as shown:

```
public class A {    
  double pay =0.0;    
  public double calculatePay(int hoursWorked,double rate) {    
    pay = hoursWorked*rate;      
    return pay;
  }    
}

public class B extends A {
  public double calculatePay(int hours,double rate) {    
    return super.calculatePay(hours,rate);
  }
}

public class C extends B { 

  public double calculatePay(int hoursWorked,double rate) {    
          //overridden implementation
  }    

  public double show() {

    //calling calculatePay from B will ultimately call it from A
     double paid = super.calculatePay(10, 1.3);
     return paid;
 }
```

For the confusion regarding How calculatePay is invoked without using instance of class C or A. To invoke the method you can use Instance of the class or `this` or simply the name of method.

```
public class Test {

    String s;

    private String hey() {
        return s;
    }

    public String getS(){
        String sm = this.hey(); // or simply hey();
        // here I could just write hey(); without this

        return sm;
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand very well your code above but in mine B is empty and am calling calculatPay from A within C  without using an instance and it works fine ,this is what i mean calculatePay(int ,double); ?

Comment: That's due to the inheritance, B extends A, and C extends B... so if you call a method using instance of C and that method is not available in C then it will be looked in B, If it is not found even in B, then it will be looked up in A and so on. So in your case method is being invoked from A.

Comment: But a case can be when you override the method calculatePay in class C, but you still want to use the method defined in class A(implemented differently), then in that case `super` keyword comes in handy.

Comment: sorry for the bother but i did not use an instance of c to call calculatePay() like c.calculatePay(),what i did was simply wrote calculatePay() and passed the parameters and it worked.How ?

Comment: because calling calculatePay in class C without instance is identical to calling `this.calculatePay();`  which means that you are calling it using an object of C, "Remember `this` is always default object present in the class?" So `this` is working as the current object (of class C) for invoking the method calculatePay()

Comment: aah wonderful ,thanks i,v got all the clarification now thank you very much for your time

Comment: But as i mentioned, A case can be there when you override calculatePay in class C, then to call the method from class A you have to implement what I have suggested in my answer. Anyways I think you got your answer. Cheers. ;)

Comment: yes i got that too ,using super and overriding too, thanks :)